# Rename Document Key Arango DB

Tags: nosql, arangodb

I have an existing collection in ArangoDB. However there is a typo in one the document Keys.

Is it possible to rename a given Key in all documents in Arangodb ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the actual attribute name you can use some similar to the following AQL:

```
FOR t IN test1
//FILTER t._key == '299'   //optional filter
UPDATE t WITH {
    potato: t.Potatoe,
    Potatoe: null
    }
IN test1 
OPTIONS { keepNull: false }
```

In the AQL above, we add a new attribute (potato), set the value to the value of the original attribute (Potatoe) and then set the original attribute to null. Finally, we use the keepNull option to tell the system to remove the Potatoe attribute.

Note that the AQL above will only remove the nulls that are the result of the statement. So if you have a 'rice' attribute in your table that is already null, the system will not delete it since 'rice' is not part of the update statement.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a systematic aberation, use an AQL-Update statement, e.g.:

```
FOR c IN collection
    FILTER c.pointer == OFFENDING_KEY
    LET newC = {pointer: CORRECT_KEY}
    UPDATE c WITH newC IN collection OPTIONS {exclusive: true}
```

Comment: In my collection, I m having ".Main_ID": 11400 but , I would like just to rename ".Main_ID" with "Main_ID". Looks like your query will update values

Comment: Yes, I understood your question that way; You can read up on AQL, a solution is not that different from the given query -- Alas, I'm short on time -- I'll update probably Monday, if you haven't found a way by then.